# E: Unable to locate package mingw32, Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, compiling, mingw

I would like to compile some C programs for Windows. So I used a search engine and I found that I probably need to install `mingw32`.

If I run:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw32
```

and I got:

> ```
> E: Unable to locate package mingw32
> ```

So, I used a search engine again, and I found [this answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689935/unable-to-locate-package-mingw32) and [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229068/unable-to-locate-package-mingw32).

I ran:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But I still the same error. What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On modern Debian derivatives, including Mint, `mingw32` is no longer available; it has been replaced by [`mingw-w64`](https://tracker.debian.org/mingw-w64):

```
sudo apt install mingw-w64
```

should work.

This package provides both 32- and 64-bit Windows compilers. When switching from `mingw32` to `mingw-w64`, you’ll need to adjust the target triplets:

- `i686-w64-mingw32` for 32-bit Windows;
- `x86_64-w64-mingw32` for 64-bit Windows.